# Spinning polygon at plane

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations, plane-geometry

Given a polygon $P$ and some line $l$, Crossing the polygon with some angel $θ$ relative to the $x$ axis, I am Intrested In spinning the polygon, And the line $l$ In such way that the line will be vertical to $x$ axis.

For example, I wish to go from (1) to (2):

[image: Polygon spin]

One possible direction I was thinking about Is to add some constans to each of the points of the polygon, But I don't know how to do it correctly.

Any help will be appericiated :)

Comment: You should rotate the polygon by $90°-\theta$ counterclockwise.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes I know that, But how should I do it?

Comment: https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/rotation_2d.html